# How Do I Communicate With A USB Scanner?

Tags: c++, qt, usb, vcf-vcard

I'm building an application in C++, that will be deployed on Windows. I kind of got thrown into this, and I've managed to make my way through 80% of the project requirements, but I'm having a hang up on one of the requirements:

I need to interface with a Business Card Scanner on a USB port. Is there a standard way of doing this, and if so, can someone give me a list of steps I need to take?

The thing is built on the Qt Framework, if that makes any difference.

Thanks,
Goldentoa11

Comment: Does the scanner have WIA support? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Image_Acquisition

Comment: If it works like a usual scanner, [WIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Image_Acquisition) and/or [TWAIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TWAIN) should be supported. Otherwise, check with the manufacturer of the device; they would know how to communicate with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[C++ Wrapper for TWAIN](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/296/A-C-Wrapper-for-TWAIN) is a good start, it's an MFC exampel but the base class is simple enough.

(assuming the scanner supports TWAIN of course !)

Comment: Please download all files from CODE-PROJECT and put it in Dropbox. Because Code-project always ask new user to register and that is like in early days when computer started. Can you please make it more reliable answer by answering or migrating that old answer to 2016 version?